# What is this thing?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Here is a riddle from my side. I think it's bit easy.

Clues

1. 8 times a day.
2. Bent
3. 97 of the cent useless.
4. It saves you from death but you can also die within it.
5. Might cause a war.

Comment: Attention that the riddle begins after clues. If you have any doubt related to question, do mention it in comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may provide a solution

> water

8 times a day

> There's a saying 'drink eight glasses of water a day'.

Bent

> The water molecule H-O-H is V-shaped or bent.

97 of the cent useless

> 97% of the water on Earth is salty ocean water which is not good for drinking.

It saves you from death but you can also die within it

> You need water to survive, but may drown in it.

Might cause a war

> Water conflict is a serious concern.

Comment: Exactly the intended one. For hint 5 rot 13(Sbe uvag 5, gur vagraqrq bar jnf gur fcrphyngvba bs Guveq Jbeyq Jne qhr gb vg.) was intended but still you earn a check.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an answer? I'm not sure how this applies to #4 or #5, but it works reasonably well for 1, 2, and 3.

> The number $3$

1. 8 times a day

> $1/8$ of a day is $3$ hours.

2. Bent

> The physical shape of the number $3$ is clearly bent.

3. 97 of the cent useless.

> Something that is $97$ percent useless is $3$ percent useful.

Again, not sure how this could work for #4 or #5. I'll have to think on it.

Comment: Sorry but not the intended answer. Good try and carry on.